# Cannot make rolling update with kuberenetes nginx controller - temporary (about 0.3s) connect() failed (111: Connection refused) happens

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, terraform, kubernetes-helm

I'm having trouble making nginx rolling update with helm_release.

```
resource "helm_release" "server" {
  name          = "server"
  chart         = "server"
  repository    = "../../charts"
  version       = var.api_version
  namespace     = kubernetes_namespace.server.metadata.0.name
  recreate_pods = false
  reuse_values  = true
  force_update  = true
  set {
    name  = "envName"
    value = var.rg_name
  }

  set {
    name = "autoscaling.minReplicas"
    value = 2
  }

  set {
    name  = "ingress.hosts[0].host"
    value = join(".", [var.rg_name, var.domain])
  }
  set {
    name  = "ingress.hosts[0].paths[0].path"
    value = join("", ["/", var.api_path, "(/|$)", "(.*)"])
  }
  set {
    name  = "image.tag"
    value = var.api_version
    type  = "string"
  }
  values = [templatefile("environment/server.yaml",
    {
      env = env
    }
  )]
}
```

and

```
resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress" {
  name       = "nginx-ingress-controller"
  namespace  = kubernetes_namespace.ingress_namespace.metadata.0.name
  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart      = "nginx-ingress-controller"
  depends_on = [kubernetes_namespace.ingress_namespace]

  set {
    name  = "rbac.enable"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "annotations.kubernetes\\.io/ingress\\.class"
    value = "azure/application-gateway"
  }

  set {
    name  = "rbac.createRole"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "rbac.createClusterRole"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "service.externalTrafficPolicy"
    value = "Local"
  }

  set {
    name  = "service.loadBalancerIP"
    value = data.azurerm_public_ip.nginx_ingress.ip_address
  }
}
```

It works great in common, but when I try to upgrade my `helm_release`, it emits 503 error under a second. When I look at to the nginx-ingress-controller, it says

```
2024/02/07 23:01:33 [error] 165#165: *25582 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 20.245.156.38, server: server.url, re  │ quest: "GET /api/dev/version HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.244.1.28:8080/dev/version", host: "server.url"
```

That connection is directing just deleted pod's IP, and if that's the case, I want to route it to alive one. I see pods are deleting after creation, but don't know why this happens though.
I want some kind of graceful rollup, not having disconnection. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Consider to ask questions related to installation of pre-made software on https://serverfault.com instead.

Comment: What is the provider configuration for kubernetes and helm?